# QImage конвертация картинки

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

Есть картинка в `bmp` формате открываю её с помощью диалога выбора файла, **нужно её конвертировать в `jpg` формат средствами `qt`, как это сделать?** далее по нажатию кнопки "вывести на форму" картинка формата `jpg` выводится в виджет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JPG` - это файловый контейнер, плюс кодек. Прежде чем вывести jpeg-картинку на экран, данные проходят конвертацию в один из удобных для рисования форматов. То же самое с `BMP`.

Открыть любой из поддерживаемого формата файлов изображений можно так:

```
QImage img("my_image.bmp");
```

Сохранить ранее открытый файл в другой формат так:

```
img.save("my_image.jpg");
```

Нарисовать `QImage` на виджете проще всего, используя `QLabel`:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
```

... или без `QImage`:

```
QLabel *label = new QLabel(this);
label->setPixmap(QPixmap("my_image.bmp"));
```

Если хочется рисовать на фоне произвольного виджета, потребуется переопределить событие `QWidget::paintEvent()`:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPixmap pix("my_image.bmp");
    if(pix.isNull() == false) {
        QRect dst_rc = rect();

        if(dst_rc.width() > dst_rc.height())
            pix = pix.scaledToHeight(dst_rc.height());
        else if(dst_rc.height() > dst_rc.width())
            pix = pix.scaledToWidth(dst_rc.width());

        dst_rc = pix.rect();
        dst_rc.moveCenter(rect().center());

        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPixmap(dst_rc, pix);
    }

    event->accept();
}
```

**Дополнение**

Загрузку файла изображения непосредственно в `paintEvent()` лучше не осуществлять, поскольку операция эта может оказаться ощутимо затратной, да и производиться будет каждый раз при перерисовке виджета. Лучше вынести это в отдельный метод класса виджета, принимающего в качестве атрибута имя файла.

Ещё, как вариант, можно задействовать кэш:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    const QString fname("my_image.bmp");

    QPixmap pix;
    if(QPixmapCache::find(fname, &pix) == false) {
        pix.load(fname);
        if(pix.isNull() == false) {
            QRect dst_rc = rect();

            if(dst_rc.width() > dst_rc.height())
                pix = pix.scaledToHeight(dst_rc.height());
            else if(dst_rc.height() > dst_rc.width())
                pix = pix.scaledToWidth(dst_rc.width());

            QPixmapCache::insert(fname, pix);
        }
    }

    if(pix.isNull() == false) {
        QRect dst_rc = pix.rect();
        dst_rc.moveCenter(rect().center());

        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.drawPixmap(dst_rc, pix);
    }

    event->accept();
}
```

В варианте кода с кэшем изображение будет загружено и преобразовано под размер виджета лишь один раз. Далее, пока жив кэш, будет лишь рисоваться, что конечно сэкономит ресурсы.

На всякий случай отмечу, что объекты в глобальном статическом `QPixmapCache` живут не более 30 секунд. Если это не устраивает, то можно использовать `QCache` или что-то своё производное.

Comment: Спасибо, далее просто планируется передавать картинку jpg и сообщения по сокету клиенту, но это уже отдельная тема.

Comment: @Disastricks, пожалуйста. Создавайте новый вопрос, если с чем-то возникнут проблемы.